# Rails deployment on ec2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using Capistrano to deploy my rails app to ec2 VM. I am following along with this tutorial https://gist.github.com/ThomasBush/584dc1e999b34177dd4436c5edb1b24d

I am using ruby version 2.6.5

Capistrano Log:
DEBUG [3b5b580d] Command: cd /home/deploy/editorial_board/releases/20210607071516 && ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.6.5" ; $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle install --jobs 4 --quiet )
DEBUG [3b5b580d]   Your Ruby version is 2.6.5, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.1

I have checked ruby -v in my local machine and on ec2 VM and i am getting my ruby version 2.6.5
Also in my gemfile specified version is 2.6.5
In .ruby-version file version is 2.6.5
In Capfile set :rbenv_ruby, '2.6.5'

I am not getting where 2.7.1 is specified, and how to get it deployed

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ThomasBush/584dc1e999b34177dd4436c5edb1b24d#file-youtube-video-commands-L40

Answer (score 1):

delete Gemfile.lock and run `bundle install` again.

And check if you installed rbenv on your ec2 instance.